# Session Timeout Redirect to Login Page in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

HI,

I am maintaing Session in Silverlight App via webservice(WCF).
Now i want to redirect to login page when user is idle for 2 minutes/session expires(After 2 minute).

Currently i am doing like this :

WCF:

```
 [OperationContract]
        public int GetSessionTimeOut()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout;
        }
```

web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout ="2" ></sessionState>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
void Welcome_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



SessionService.SLWebServiceClient client = new SessionService.SLWebServiceClient();
                client.GetSessionTimeOutCompleted += new EventHandler<SessionService.GetSessionTimeOutCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetSessionTimeOutCompleted);
                client.GetSessionTimeOutAsync(); 


        }

        void client_GetSessionTimeOutCompleted(object sender, SessionService.GetSessionTimeOutCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            int result = e.Result;
       }
```

What to do after this step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.Current.RootVisual = new LoginPage();

Comment: But how it will know User is Idle for 2 minutes not session has to expired and redirect to login page ?

Comment: You can subscribe to events which determine user activity, f.i. MouseMove. Start the timer, and reset it on each user activity, if interval between user's activity is 2 minutes you should change root visual ( in case with Navigation Framework you can redirect user). But I advice to redirect user on login page only if asp.net session is expired.

Comment: How to check that asp.net session is expired

Comment: If you got Communicationexception on service call, service should be asp.net compatible